# Extend or extended?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Recently when I wanted to submit a research paper on a conference web site I saw something like this:

> "In answer to many requests, it was decided to extended the paper submission."

And I'm wondering if it's correct English. Shouldn't it be written as:

> "In answer to many requests, it was decided to extend the paper submission."

I know that if we want to say that we have more time to submit the paper, we can use other words: " The paper submission was extended". Then the "extended" word is used correctly. Am I right, or is the first sentence still grammatically correct? If so, why?

Comment: [Some verbs are followed by the **to-infinitive:**](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/node/1404/) - in particular, *verbs of **thinking and feeling***, such as *choose, **decide**, expect, forget, hate, hope, intend, learn, like, love, mean, plan, prefer, remember*.

Comment: Note that with some verbs, such as *He helped me [**to**] survive*, it's still an infinitive, but including the explicit ***to*** marker may be effectively "optional". And with some others, such as *I heard her sing*, it's actually ungrammatical to include ***to*** (but again, *sing* there is an infinitive).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> In answer to many requests, it was decided **to extended** the paper submission.

What you have there is just patently wrong. We're talking about the basics of English grammar here. You can't have the past tense form (or past participle for that matter) of a verb be part of the infinitive form of that verb. They're mutually exclusive, if you will. It should be *to extend*, of course. The reason why is because in English a verb that follows the main verb in a sentence or clause must be put in infinitive form. This rule breaks in certain, though very rare, circumstances. For example, most people instead of saying *I'm gonna go to check on the dinner* will say *I'm gonna go check on the dinner*. Notice, there is no *to* between *go* and *check*.

> "The paper submission was extended". Then the "extended" word is used correctly. Am I right?

Yes, you're absolutely right. That's because *was extended* is something grammarians call a passive voice. It is formed by following any of the conjugated forms of the verb *to be* with the past participle of the verb that you're using.